# Textures causing problems

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glut, glm-math

I am trying to make a table in OpenGL and placing a texture onto the table. When I created the table using OpenGL colors rather than textures it worked just fine. However, when I added in the texture code, everything broke. Now the table looks like a piece of paper that has been crushed into a ball. It looks like the program doesn't understand where the vertices should go?

**Here is the code I have written:**

```
// Header Inclusions
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

// GLM Math Header inclusions
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

// SOIL Image loader Inclusion
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"

using namespace std; // Standard namespace

#define WINDOW_TITLE "Zane's CameraOrbit" // Window title Macro

// Shader program Macro
#ifndef GLSL
#define GLSL(Version, Source) "#version " #Version "\n" #Source
#endif

// Variable declarations for shader, window size initialization, buffer and array objects
GLint shaderProgram, WindowWidth = 800, WindowHeight = 600;
GLuint VBO, VAO, texture;
GLfloat degrees = glm::radians(-45.0f); // Converts float to degrees

GLfloat cameraSpeed = 0.0005f; // Movement speed per frame

GLchar currentKey; // will store key pressed
bool proj = true;


GLfloat lastMouseX = 400, lastMouseY = 300; // Locks mouse cursor at the center of the screen
GLfloat mouseXOffset, mouseYOffset, yaw = 0.0f, pitch = 0.0f; // mouse offset, yaw, and pitch variables
GLfloat sensitivity = 0.005f; // Used for mouse / camera rotation sensitivity
bool mouseDetected = true; // Initially true when mouse movement is detected

// Global vector declarations
glm::vec3 cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Initial camera position. Placed 5 units in Z
glm::vec3 CameraUpY = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Temporary y unit vector
glm::vec3 CameraForwardZ = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); // Temporary Z unit vector
glm::vec3 front; // Temporary Z unit vector for mouse


// Function prototypes
void UResizeWindow(int, int);
void URenderGraphics(void);
void UCreateShader(void);
void UCreateBuffers(void);
void UGenerateTexture(void);
void UKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void UKeyReleased(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

void UMouseMove(int x, int y);


// Vertex Shader Source Code
const GLchar * vertexShaderSource = GLSL(330,
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; // Vertex data from Vertex Attrib Pointer 0
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 textureCoordinate;

    out vec2 mobileTextureCoordinate;

    //Global variables for the transform matrices
        uniform mat4 model;
        uniform mat4 view;
        uniform mat4 projection;

void main(){
        gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f); // transforms vertices to clip coordinates
        mobileTextureCoordinate = vec2(textureCoordinate.x, 1.0f - textureCoordinate.y); // flips the texture horizontal
    }
);


// Fragment Shader Source Code
const GLchar * fragmentShaderSource = GLSL(330,

        in vec2 mobileTextureCoordinate;

        out vec4 gpuTexture; // Variable to pass color data to the GPU

        uniform sampler2D uTexture; // Useful when working with multiple textures

    void main(){

        gpuTexture = texture(uTexture, mobileTextureCoordinate);
    }
);

// Main program
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);

    glutReshapeFunc(UResizeWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

    UCreateShader();

    UCreateBuffers();

    UGenerateTexture();

    // Use the Shader program
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color

    glutDisplayFunc(URenderGraphics);

    glutKeyboardFunc(UKeyboard);

    glutKeyboardUpFunc(UKeyReleased);

    glutPassiveMotionFunc(UMouseMove); // Detects mouse movement

    glutMainLoop();

    // Destroys Buffer objects once used
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    return 0;
}


// Resizes the window
void UResizeWindow(int w, int h)
{
    WindowWidth = w;
    WindowHeight = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
}

// Renders graphics
void URenderGraphics(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable z-depth

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clears the screen

    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // Activates the vertex array object before rednering and transforming them

    CameraForwardZ = front; // Replaces camera forward vector with Radians normalized as unit vector

    //Transforms the object
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // Place the object at the center of the viewport
    model = glm::rotate(model, 45.0f, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f)); // Rotate the object 45 degrees on the X
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f)); // Increase the object size by a scale of 2

    // Transforms the camera THIS DIFFERS FROM TUTORIAL
    glm::mat4 view;
    view = glm::lookAt(CameraForwardZ, cameraPosition, CameraUpY);

    // Creates a perspective projection THIS DIFFERS FROM TUTORIAL
    glm::mat4 projection;
    if(proj)
        projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)WindowWidth / (GLfloat)WindowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    else
        projection = glm::ortho(-5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // Retrieves and passes transform matrices to the shader program
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
    GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glutPostRedisplay();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Draws the triangles
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 156);

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Deactivate the Vertex Array Object

    glutSwapBuffers(); // Flips the back buffer with the front buffer every frame.
}

// Creates the Shader program
void UCreateShader()
{

    // Vertex shader
    GLint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); // Creates the Vertex shader
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL); // Attaches the Vertex shader to the source code
    glCompileShader(vertexShader); // Compiles the Vertex shader

    // Fragment shader
    GLint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); // Creates the Fragment shader
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL); // Attaches the fragment shader to the source code
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader); // Compiles the fragment shader

    //Shader program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram(); // Creates the Shader program and returns an id
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader); // Attach Vertex shader to the shader program
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);; // Attach Fragment shader to the Shader program
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram); // Link Vertex and Fragment shaders to Shader program

    // Delete the Veretx and Fragment shaders once linked
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}


void UCreateBuffers()
{
    GLfloat vertices[] = {

                                //Positions             //Color

                                //Back
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,

                                //Front
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,

                                //Left side
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,

                                //Right side
                                0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,

                                //Bottom
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.5f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,

                                //Top
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, 0.10f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,

                                /*BOTTOM LEFT LEG(1)*/

                                // bottom left leg(1) left
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, -0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, -0.60f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, -0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(1) front
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, -0.60f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, -0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, -0.60f,      0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(1) right
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, -0.80f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(1) back
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, -0.80f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, -0.80f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, -0.80f,      0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(1) bottom
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,     0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,     0.0f, 1.0f,

                                /*BOTTOM RIGHT LEG(1)*/

                                // bottom right leg(1) left
                                0.60f, -0.5f, -0.80f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.80f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f, -0.60f,       0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f, -0.80f,       1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom right leg(1) front
                                0.60f, -0.5f, -0.60f,       0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f, -0.60f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f, -0.60f,       0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(1) right
                                0.45f, -0.5f, -0.60f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f,  -0.80f, -0.80f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f, -0.80f,       0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f, -0.60f,       1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(1) back
                                0.45f, -0.5f, -0.80f,       0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f,  -0.80f, -0.80f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.80f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f, -0.80f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f, -0.80f,       0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(1) bottom
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.80f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.60f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, -0.80f,      0.0f, 1.0f,

                                /*BOTTOM LEFT LEG(2)*/

                                // bottom left leg(2) left
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f,  0.80f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,       1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(2) front
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, 0.80f,       0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, 0.80f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, 0.80f,       0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(2) right
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f,  0.60f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f,  0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(2) back
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,       0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.45f, -0.5f, 0.60f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,       0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom left leg(2) bottom
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.80f, -0.80f, 0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f,

                                /*BOTTOM RIGHT LEG(2)*/

                                // bottom right leg(2) left
                                0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,        1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f,   0.80f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,        1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom right leg(2) front
                                0.60f, -0.5f, 0.80f,        0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f, 0.80f,        0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f, 0.80f,        0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom right leg(2) right
                                0.45f, -0.5f, 0.80f,        1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f,   0.60f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f,   0.80f,      1.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom right leg(2) back
                                0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,        0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.45f, -0.5f, 0.60f,        0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.60f, -0.5f, 0.60f,        0.0f, 0.0f,

                                // bottom right leg(2) bottom
                                0.80f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.80f,       1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.70f, -0.80f, 0.60f,       0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.80f, -0.80f,  0.60f,      0.0f, 1.0f



                    };

    //Generate buffer ids
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // Activates the Vertex Array Object before binding and setting any VBOs and Vertex Attribute Pointers.
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    //Activate the VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Copy vertices to VBO

    // Set attribute pointer 0 to hold Position data
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Enables vertex attribute

    // Set attribute pointer 2 to hold Color data
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // Enables vertex attribute

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Deactivates the VAO which is good practice
}

/*Generate and load the texture*/
void UGenerateTexture(){

            glGenTextures(1, &texture);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

            int width, height;

            unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("woodTable.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB); // Loads texture file

            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            SOIL_free_image_data(image);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind the texture
}


void UKeyboard(unsigned char key, GLint x, GLint y)
{
    switch(key){
    case 'o':
        currentKey = key;
        proj = !proj;
        break;

    }
}

void UKeyReleased(unsigned char key, GLint x, GLint y)
{
    cout<<"Key released" <<endl;
    currentKey = '0';
}

// Implements the UMouseMove function
void UMouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    // Immediately replaces center locked coordinates with new mouse coordinates
    if(mouseDetected)
        {
            lastMouseX = x;
            lastMouseY = y;
            mouseDetected = false;
        }

        // Gets the direction the mouse was moved in x and y
        mouseXOffset = x - lastMouseX;
        mouseYOffset = lastMouseY - y; // Inverted Y

        //Updates with new mouse coordinates
        lastMouseX = x;
        lastMouseY = y;

        // Applies sensitivity to mouse direction
        mouseXOffset *= sensitivity;
        mouseYOffset *= sensitivity;

        // Accumulates the yaw and pitch variables
        yaw += mouseXOffset;
        pitch += mouseYOffset;

        // Orbits around the center
        front.x = 10.0f * cos(yaw);
        front.y = 10.0f * sin(pitch);
        front.z = sin(yaw) * cos(pitch) * 10.f;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertex attribute array consists vertex coordinates with 3 components (*x*, *y*, *z*) and texture coordinates with 2 components (*u*, *v*). Thus an attrbute  tuple has 5 components (*x*, *y*, *z*, *u*, *v*).
The *stride* argument of for [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes. Hence the argument has to be `5 * sizeof(GLfloat)` (`(3 + 2) * sizeof(GLfloat)`) rather than `6 * sizeof(GLfloat)`:

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
```

and

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your reply! It worked! 

If I may, can I ask one more question?
As I said, I am pretty new to this, so when you said "The vertex attribute array consists of tuples with 5 components", what does this mean? and How can I know when to use a different number in another situation?

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @ZaneBrown *"The vertex attribute array consists of tuples with 5 components"* you missed the important part *"(x, y, z, u, v)"*. Your array consists of vertex coordinates with 3 components (x, y, z) and texture coordinates with 2 components (u, v). The stride argument specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes. In your case `(3+2)*sizeof(GLfloat)`.